# Function that has a point with zero derivative and that point is not maximum nor minimum and not inflection point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Can you find an example of a function that has a point with zero derivative 
>   and that point is not maximum nor minimum and not inflection point?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  What have you tried so far?  Do you have any thoughts on what the graph would look like?

Comment: I'm taking calculus course, and I was given than question.

Comment: maybe, x^2(sin(1/x)) works? if f(0) defined to be 0. and I'm looking at the point where x = 0.

Comment: Are you able to show that $0$ is not a maximum/minumum/inflection for such $f$?

Comment: I'm having a bit of a trouble proving it has no inflection.

Comment: A saddle point pehaps in 3D,  with horizontal ( parallel to an axis) tangent..

Answer (score 2):

What about $f(x)=x^a\sin(1/x)$ with $a>0$ extended by continuity at $0$. Are you able to find $a$ such that the given conditions are satisfied?

Comment: I thought about something similar but how do I prove it has no inflection at 0?

Comment: What definition of inflection are you using? BTW you take a larger $a$ if you have troubles with $a=2$.

Comment: if there is neighbourhood where (x,x+h) is convex and (x-h,x) is concave or (x,x+h) is concave and (x-h,x) is convex. in this case x=0

Comment: Find the secon derivativee and showthat it changes sign infinitely times in a neighbourhood of zero